# How to update cart from shop page when product quantity increase/decrease in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Here is the code I am using for updating my cart with ajax in CART page-

```
jQuery('div.woocommerce').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Its working fine , but my problem is when I try with same code in shop page its not updating my cart -
Here is what i have tried -

```
jQuery('li.product').on('change keyup mouseup', 'input.qty', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
    if (timeout != undefined) clearTimeout(timeout); //cancel previously scheduled event
    if (jQuery(this).val() == '') return; //qty empty, instead of removing item from cart, do nothing
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('[name="update_cart"]').trigger('click');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Here is the link if u want to check(https://cdn.royalancer.co.uk/test/).

Comment: The answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45710409/replace-add-to-cart-with-custom-quantity-input-fields-in-woocmmerce

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
jQuery('li.product').on('change keyup mouseup', 'button.plus.qib-button,button.minus.qib-button', function(){ // keyup and mouseup for Firefox support
   var timeout;
   var this_ = jQuery(this);
       timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       this_.parent().parent().find('.ajax_add_to_cart').trigger( 'click' );
       clearTimeout(timeout);
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Comment: can u just check the link, its working but both ways its just increasing the product not decreasing :(

Comment: i think it would be only for plus button,minus button should have a different script .isnt it?

Comment: Minus and plus both buttons are for quantity increases and decrease. It will not remove item from cart.

Comment: u have not provided any value bro.ur script only increase value which is already doing woocommerce add to cart button. i have already the solution will update it here soon