# so i used this code in wordpress snippets to display a plus and minus but cant display it on single product template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

**i recently added some custom function  to a website that uses elmentor in order to display the quantity in a nice  ui, it is showing very nicely and firing all request with the ajax correctly on the product archive pages but not on single product pages.
problem is i cannot make it work on the single product pages - it simply wont fire up.**

I used the code posted by @kashalo as posted here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734509/7469689
**how would you add that ?**
second issue is i cant seem to be able to add variations that display a true false field to the woocommerce shop and product archives without using a plugin.
i tried looking into the wordpress codex and on other places but there is not a single guide into how or where i should start.
desired actions:

1. add a quantity select box without any plugins to woocommerce shop and product archive pages, and single product pages that updates the cart with ajax
   2.add product ariations with 2 options nly as a nice or even a true / false slider /select box without any plugins
   this is how it looks now
   [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIDHw.png)
   and this how i want it to look :
   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQrea.png)

this is the code i used :

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'QTY');
function QTY()
{
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="shopAddToCart">
    <button  value="-" class="minus"  >-</button>
    <input type="text"
    disabled="disabled"
    size="2"
    value="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['QTY'] : 0;
    ?>"
    id="count"
    data-product-id= "<?php echo $product->get_id() ?>"
    data-in-cart="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['in_cart'] : 0;
    ?>"
    data-in-cart-qty="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['QTY'] : 0;
    ?>"
    class="quantity  qty"
    max_value = <?php echo ($product->get_max_purchase_quantity() == -1) ? 1000 : $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(); ?>
    min_value = <?php echo $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(); ?>
    >

    <button type="button" value="+" class="plus"  >+</button>

    </div>
                          <?php
}

function Check_if_product_in_cart($product_ids)
 {

foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item):

    $items_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $QTY = $cart_item['quantity'];

    // for a unique product ID (integer or string value)
    if ($product_ids == $items_id):
        return ['in_cart' => true, 'QTY' => $QTY];

    endif;

endforeach;
}
add_action('wc_ajax_update_qty', 'update_qty');

function update_qty()
{
    ob_start();
    $product_id = absint($_POST['product_id']);
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item):

        if ($cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id) {
            WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $quantity, true);
        }

    endforeach;

    wp_send_json('done');
}
```

JS for event actions :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  // Add Event Listner on the Plush button 
  $('.plus').click(function () {

    if (parseInt($(this).prev().val()) < parseInt($(this).prev().attr('max_value'))) {
      $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);

      var currentqty = parseInt($(this).prev().attr('data-in-cart-qty')) + 1;

      var id = $(this).prev().attr('data-product-id');

      var data = {
        product_id: id,
        quantity: 1
      };
      $(this).prev().attr('data-in-cart-qty', currentqty);
      $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
      $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function (response) {

        if (!response) {
          return;
        }

        if (response) {

          var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
          url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
          $.post(url, function (data, status) {
            $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
            if (data.fragments) {
              jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

                jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
              });
            }
            jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
          });
          $('.plus').parent().removeClass('loading');

        }

      });


    }




  });



  $('.minus').click(function () { if ($(this).next().val() > 0) {

    $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);


    var currentqty = parseInt($(this).next().val());

    var id = $(this).next().attr('data-product-id');

    var data = {
      product_id: id,
      quantity: currentqty
    };
    $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
    $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'update_qty'), data, function (response) {

      if (!response) {
        return;
      }

      if (response) {
        var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
        url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
        $.post(url, function (data, status) {
          $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
          if (data.fragments) {
            jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

              jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
            });
          }
          jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
        });
        $('.plus').parent().removeClass('loading');
      }

    });



}
  });



});
```